# When are Thymeleaf expression delimiters needed in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE with Thymeleaf. From the Thymeleaf documentation it's not clear to me when I must use the `${}` delimiters in a Thymeleaf expression.

For example I had this in my template, and it was working:

```html
<div th:title="${doTest() ? 'foo' : 'bar'}" />
```

But then I reread the docs and I see that I could use this:

```html
<div th:title="${doTest()} ? 'foo' : 'bar'" />
```

But the `? … : …` ternary operator is an operator, so thus the whole thing is an expression. So why don't I need the `${}` around the whole attribute value?

Could I also do this?

```html
<div th:title="doTest() ? 'foo' : 'bar'" />
```

What about this?

```html
<div th:title="'foo'" />
```

Why one and not the other?

What about this? Can I use just a bare `true`?

```html
<div th:if="true">…</div>
```

Or do I need expression delimiters?

```html
<div th:if="${true}">…</div>
```

Here's another example: I see this in the documentation:

```html
<li th:text="${item.description}" …
```

But can I just use `th:text="item.description"`? What do the braces do for me?

I also see this:

```html
th:each="item : ${items}"
```

Can I just use `th:each="item : items"` instead? Why wouldn't Thymeleaf know to evaluate `items` without the braces in `${items}`?

Surely there must be some simple rule for when I need `${}`, but it's not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 3):

using an expression without `${}` will be considered as a mix of ***values***(strings, numbers booleans ...), operations and conditions, thus thymeleaf will try to execute the expression as it is. this is ***Thymeleaf Standard Expression engine***

for example :

`th:text="item.description"` : will display `item.description`, the same if you do `th:text="'item.description'"` because thymeleaf looks at `item.description` as a text [docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-tokens).

now using `${}`  with an expression, will be considered as variable expression meaning every literal token(text without '') is a variable that will be executed within a pre-defined Context.this is ***OGNL(Object-Graph Navigation Language)***

in our example:

`th:text="${item.description}"`: will display the description of the item object in the context. in spring you can register your object in the context using `Model`(or `ModelAndView`):
`model.addAttribute("item", new Item());` this will throw an exception if no `item` is found in the context.

so `th:text="${'item.description'}"` and `th:text="item.description"` is the same but they are evaluated differently.

**I think it's clear now that if you want to have access to objects( models, services, repositories...) from within your templates you should use `${}`.**

Comment: I think what you're saying is that `th:text="item.description"` and `th:text="${item.description}"` are both considered expressions, but in the former `item.description` is considered a token, not a variable reference. OK, so what about `th:text="item.getDescription()"`? Would that be allowed? Would it invoke the method, or must I place it inside `${…}`?

Comment: actually  that's not what I said. ${...} is variable expression and " .." is a  non* variable expression. so you have to add ${} in order to invoke the method ('item' should be  defined)

Comment: But isn't the whole thing an expression (I didn't say "variable expression") even without the `${}`? Otherwise, how would `th:text="true ? 'yes' : 'no'"` evaluate?

Comment: `th:text="true ? 'yes' : 'no '"` it's not a variable expression, so all the text inside are either values(`yes` and `no`') or tokens that thymeleaf understands (true is boolean,  Elvis operator...). so  it will display `yes`

Answer (score 2):

- For example I had this in my template, and it was working:- ***Yes because this is executed by executed by `OGNL(Object-Graph Navigation Language)`***

```html
<div th:title="{$doTest() ? 'foo' : 'bar'}" />
```

- But then I reread the docs and I see that I could use this:- ***Yes because this is executed by `Thymeleaf Standard Expression engine`.***

```html
<div th:title="{$doTest()} ? 'foo' : 'bar'" />
```

- But the `? :` an operator, so thus the whole thing is an expression. So why don't I need the `${}` around the whole attribute value? - ***Because thymeleaf has `Elvis Operator (?:)` natively. So the `Thymeleaf Standard Expression engine` is able to execute it.***
- What about this? Can I use just a bare true?

  In Thymeleaf, any value can be evaluated to a boolean. We have a few values
  interpreted as `false`:

  - List item
  - null
  - the boolean value false
  - the number 0
  - the character \0
  - the strings “false”, “off”and “no”

***Any other value is evaluated to `true`.***

- Here are some useful links :-

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-conditionals

https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-boolean

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#variables

http://commons.apache.org/ognl/

**EDIT :-**

`<div th:title="{$doTest() ? 'foo' : 'bar'}" />`

`<div th:title="{$doTest()} ? 'foo' : 'bar'" />`

You can use both the above syntax in your case. Both are executed differently but end result is same. First one is executed by *OGNL* and second one by *Thymeleaf engine*.

Your doubt was why the second one works? Why don't we need to put `?:` operator inside `${}`?

Answer to above questions is that *Thymeleaf engine* understands `?:` operator natively. And it is called *Elvis Operator*. It similar to ternary opertaor we have in most programming languages but with minor differences. You can read more about it in the links i have shared.

Hence even if we don't put `?:` inside `${}` it is successfully executed by *Thymeleaf Engine*.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the core question was how I tell when I need `${}` and when I don't; and I don't feel like your answer sufficiently addressed that. For example, do I need `${}` around `${doTest()}`? Why or why not? How would I know?

Comment: That's what I tried to explain above. No problem I will add more explanation to it.

Comment: But you still haven't told me when I need curly braces at all. Can I use `th:title="doTest() ? 'foo' : 'bar'"` without any curly braces? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

We use ${}, if we need to access a variable. Variable as in your example `item.description`, where item is an object/reference and description is a string inside the object item.

Assume that `description` has a value "This is thymeleaf".

Inorder to display the text in description on the html we implement in the following way :

```
<p th:text="${item.description}"></p>
```

Output:

> This is thymeleaf

But using without the ${} expression, is going to yield the given string "item.description" itself on the html, that is the reference does not get resolved.

```
<p th:text="item.description"></p>
```

Output:

> item.description

I would like to explain another example where there could be some exceptions, especially while using `th:if` and `th:each`.

Both the expressions below are the same and going to yield the same output :

```
<p th:if="${item.description} != null"></p>
<p th:if="${item.description != null}"></p>
```

The above expression says to display the paragraph if the description inside item is not null.

Thymeleaf expects us to use ${} so that if such an expression occurs then it can compare for the words inside the braces with the variables inside it's context and return the variable value if it finds a match.

> Note : Thymeleaf maintains a context variable, accessible through #ctx
> which contains all the variables input to the template in the form of
> key value pairs.

If the variable is not enclosed with ${}, then it considers the string to be a plain text and uses them as it is.